# ESP32 HTTPS Request Issue: HTTP Request Sent Instead of HTTPS, Resulting in 307 and 400 Errors

Tags: express, http, https, esp32

I am currently facing a challenge with an ESP32 attempting to make an HTTPS request, but it seems to be sending an HTTP request instead. The project involves sending data to "https://battery-info.onrender.com/api/data-store". Interestingly, both HTTPS and HTTP versions of the route work seamlessly in Postman.

However, when emulating the ESP32 from Wokwi, I encounter two different issues:

- When attempting the HTTP version of the route ("http://battery-info.onrender.com/api/data-store"), it returns a 307 Temporary Redirect error.
- When attempting the HTTPS version of the route, it returns a 400 Bad Request error.

> Here are the key details:

- The ESP32 code is intended to make an HTTPS request.
- Postman successfully interacts with both versions of the route.
- In Wokwi emulation, HTTP leads to a 307 error, and HTTPS results in a 400 error.

on server side i have setup a simple express app with two routes. it isn't a complicated one

I am seeking guidance on how to configure the ESP32 to make a successful HTTPS request in the Wokwi environment. Any insights into potential ESP32 code adjustments or configurations to resolve these errors would be highly appreciated. If anyone has encountered similar issues or has expertise in ESP32 HTTPS communication, your assistance would be invaluable!

my arduino code

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "Wokwi-GUEST";
const char* password = "";
const char* serverName = "http://battery-info.onrender.com/api/data-store/";

WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(250);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // Create a JSON document
  StaticJsonDocument<200> jsonDoc;

  // Add data to the JSON document
  jsonDoc["ac_vol"] = 220.1;
  jsonDoc["AmpsRMS_1"] = 10.8;
  jsonDoc["Amps"] = 15.5;
  jsonDoc["dc_volt"] = 400.4;
  jsonDoc["ac_pow"] = 2400.7;
  jsonDoc["dc_pow"] = 4800.9;

  // Convert the JSON document to a string
  String jsonString;
  serializeJson(jsonDoc, jsonString);

  // Debug prints
  Serial.println("JSON Payload:");
  Serial.println(jsonString);

  // Send HTTP POST request
  http.begin(client, serverName);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(jsonString);

  // Debug prints
  Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
  Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

  // Print server response
  String response = http.getString();
  Serial.println("Server response:");
  Serial.println(response);

  http.end();

  delay(2500); // Delay before next iteration
}
```

so far i have tried

- Modifying HTTP Code to HTTPS:
  The initial step involved modifying the user's HTTP Arduino code to use HTTPS instead. This included importing the WiFiClientSecure library, creating a WiFiClientSecure object, using port 443, and setting the root certificate using the setCACert() function.

I have also used localtunnel to expose my local server and i tried the http version of that link on wokwi and it seems to work just fine, i received the data from esp32 from wokwi emulation,
but it is not a permanent solution. 
 Any idea how to fix that permanently or how to work around that?

 Should i deploy my express server elsewhere?
any suggestion will be appriciated.

Comment: check the [example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino) that came with httpclient library to see how to modify your code accordingly.